# Help with Baby Rudin Definition 11.2

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, definition

[image: text]
[image: text]

Hey all, I have a question about the equation $(9)$.
Why do we need the condition $|\phi(B)|<+\infty$? I know it may intend to avoid the case that $+\infty-(+\infty)$, but why don't we let $|\phi(A)|<+\infty$? 
I would appreciate if you could explain in details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we don't impose that $|(\phi B)|<+\infty$, then, as you wrote, we could have $\phi(A\setminus B)=\infty-\infty$, which would be meaningless. On the other hand, if we impose that $|(\phi A)|<+\infty$, then the statement will be less powerful, since it will not include the case in which $|(\phi A)|=+\infty$ and $|(\phi B)|<+\infty$, in which case the statement tells us that$$\phi(A\setminus B)=\phi(A)-\phi(B)=\pm\infty.$$

Comment: If we impose $|\phi(B)|<+\infty$, we then lose the case that $|\phi(A)|<+\infty$ and $|\phi(B)|=+\infty$. However, $\phi(A-B)=+\infty(or\ -\infty)$ in the case that we impose  $|\phi(A)|<+\infty$. Also, in the last line of your answer, why $\phi(A-B)=+\infty$? Since $\phi(\cdot)$ can take negative values, I think it may be equal to $-\infty$.

Comment: If $|\phi(A)|<+\infty$, then, since $A\subset B$, we cannot have $|\phi(B)|=+\infty$. Concerning your other question, it was a typo and I will edit it.

Comment: How about $0<\phi(A)<+\infty$ and $\phi(B)=+\infty$? I think it does not violate the monotonicity if $\phi(\cdot)$ is nonnegative.

Comment: In my previous comment, I wrote $A\subset B$, but I meant $A\supset B$. Sorry about that.